# Create Django model object with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, model

I tried so many different ways but can't seem to get it.

I have 'TeamName' as a foreign key to 'MLBGame'. I have been trying to create new MLBGame objects but cant get it to work because of the foreign key. What is the correct way to do it?

I have tried querying the foreign key like:
team = TeamName.objects.get(name=whatevername) and I tried with (name__name=whatevername)

and then inserting the team var in the new object to create but no go.

I really appreciate any help you can offer, I have been working on this for awhile and the Django docs just have me going around in circles.

```
Models

class TeamName(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MLBGame(models.Model):
    gameID = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey('TeamName',
                             null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    other stuff
```

```
team = TeamName.objects.get(name=game.away_team)

MLBGame.objects.update_or_create(
                    gameID=gameID, defaults={
                        'name': team.name,
                         Other Stuff}
                     )
```

Comment: Can you paste the error here ?

Comment: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'name' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my issue. I was trying to get the name out of the TeamName object.
in MLBGame.objects.update_or_create I hade 'name': team.name. Should have just been team.

```
Correct code:


team = TeamName.objects.get(name=somename)

MLBGame.objects.update_or_create(
                    gameID=gameID, defaults={
                        'name': team}
                     )
```